# Почему scrapy не принимает больше одного cookie?

Tags: python, scrapy

Суть вопроса такова: есть некий сайт, на него я логинюсь с помощью **phantomjs**, получаю **json** файл с куками.
После этого я хотел бы отдать эти куки scrapy, чтобы **scrapy** логинился и забирал информацию с сайта.

При тесте кода приведенного ниже на *httpbin.org/cookies*, нет полученных кук.
Если задать индекс, например **cookies[0]**, то на *httpbin.org/cookies* я получаю одну куку (что предсказуемо). Но нужно отдать все из json файла.

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    start_urls = ['http://site.ru']

    def get_cookies(self):
        os.system("phantomjs ~/ph.js")
        with open('cookie.json') as data_file:    
            data = json.load(data_file)
            print data
        return data

    def parse(self, response):
        cookies = self.get_cookies()
        return Request(url="http://httpbin.org/cookies", cookies=cookies,
        callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
        print response.body_as_unicode().encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Что `print data` печатает и в каком формате `Request` ожидает `cookies`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> r=Request(url="http://httpbin.org/cookies",cookies={'x':1,'y':2,'z':3})
>>> fetch(r)
2016-06-10 03:36:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/cookies> (referer: None)
>>> print response.body
{
  "cookies": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "2",
    "z": "3"
  }
}
```

смотри что там Phantomjs насоздавал. там же наверняка не словарь а список со словарями данных

> Если задать индекс, например cookies[0], то на httpbin.org/cookies я
>   получаю одну куку (что предсказуемо).

Request ждет словарь, а ты ему список словарей подсовываешь. но зато когда сделал правильно посчитал что это ошибка :D

вот как то так надо

```
...cookies=dict((cookie['name'],cookie['value']) for cookie in self.get_cookies())
```